# Blocked by Play Protect for a signed release APK

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-protect

I have a React Native (Android) app and for which I signed as per the instructions here;

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

I generated a release APK which is also all fine (no errors).  I then downloaded the APK to my android device and when I clicked to install I got a message to say the below.

[image]

This app is not to be published to the Play Store but we will supply a URL to our customers to download the APK.  So I want users to be able to install the APK without getting this warning.

**What I found so far**

- Disabling the play protect on the device (We don't want our customers to do this)
- Publishing to the play store (We will supply a URL to download the APK)
- Play Protect Appeals Submission Form (Is this only for apps to be published to the play store? If not, how does it work once it is verified?)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Play Protect Appeals Submission Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals) can solve your problem. Just send your apk details to Google and wait for appeal process. When you enter your apk's URL, Google will control your apk. Just enter your URL to **URL to download your APK file** section. You do not need publish your app.

Comment: Perfect.  Sounds exactly what I need.  Follow up question;  does the URL I provide must be the same URL that customers will download from? OR can I give the URL to my APK in a dropbox but then once approved by Google, host the APK on our website?

Comment: You can use anything for send to Google. Dropbox is fine.